# How to manipulate the elements of an array in an assembler subroutine in a 32-bit linux architecture?

Tags: assembly, x86

My assembler program consists of swapping two elements of an array named tab: .int 5,7. It happens that the permutation in the main program does not pose a problem, but when I use a subroutine that I call permut to which I pass the address of the table in parameter, the same operations gives me a segmentation error . I tried all the methods, using the registers containing the element addresses, trying to manipulate tab in the subroutine, using indexed addressing. In short, I tried everything that I knew for days without success. I would like to know what I did wrong and where I find the problem in my program.   Here is the program:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
tab: .int 1,5,8
li: .asciz "\n"
descrip: .asciz "%d"
debut: .asciz "            MON PROGRAMME ASSEMBLEUR\n"
bar: .asciz "=================================================\n"
.data

.global main
main:

push offset bar
call print_string
add esp,4

push offset debut
call print_string
add esp,4

push offset bar
call print_string
add esp,4

push offset tab
call affab
add esp,4


call permut


call lig
call lig

push offset tab
call affab
add esp,4

mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 0x80

permut:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov eax, [ebp+8]

    mov ebx,[eax]
    mov ecx,[eax+4]
    mov [eax],ecx
    mov [eax+4],ebx

    pop ebp
ret

affab:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    mov ecx,0
    pour:
        cmp ecx,3
        jge finpr
        push [eax+ecx*4]
        call print_int
        add esp,4
        call lig
        inc ecx
        jmp pour
        finpr:
    pop ebp
ret



print_int:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    pusha
    push [ebp+8]
    push offset descrip
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    popa
    pop ebp
ret

print_string:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    pusha
    push [ebp+8]
    call printf
    add esp, 4
    popa
    pop ebp
ret

lig:
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

    push offset li
    call print_string
    add esp,4

    pop ebp
ret
```

Comment: Your `.data` is in the wrong place. It should be before your data and you should switch back to `.text` before `main`.  PS: do not use `int 0x80` to exit. Either return from `main` or `call exit`. Also note that `ebx` is callee-saved register as per the standard calling convention.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not see this error